# Prove that $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$ is rational if and only if $a^2-b$ and $\frac{1}{2}(a+\sqrt{a^2-b})$ are square.

Tags: irrational-numbers

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a^2\geq b$. Prove that $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}$ is rational if and only if $a^2-b$ and $\frac{1}{2}(a+\sqrt{a^2-b})$ are square.

$\Rightarrow$)

$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}&= \frac{p}{q}\\
2a+2\sqrt{a^2-b}&=\frac{p^2}{q^2}\\
\frac{1}{2}(a+\sqrt{a^2-b})&=\frac{p^2}{(2q)^2}
\end{align*}$

but I don't know how to relationate $a^2-b$

$(\Leftarrow$

$\begin{align*}
n&=\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2-b}}{2}\\
&=\frac{(a+\sqrt{b})+2\sqrt{a^2+b}+(a-\sqrt{b})}{4}=\left(\frac{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}}{2}\right)^2
\end{align*}$

then $\sqrt{n}=\frac{\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}}}{2}$

but again I don't know what to do with $a^2-b$

Comment: @quasi it was a typo, but now it's fixed. Thank you. And for the other question is on $R$ not in $Q$ (Or at least in this exercise)

Comment: Can you give the source of the exercise? I suspect it was specified that $a,b$ are nonnegative rational numbers (in which case, it's easy), not just real numbers.

Comment: @quasi https://tuxdoc.com/download/fernando-zalamea-fundamentos-de-matematicas-coleccion-notas-de-clase-universidad-nacional-de-colombia-2007_pdf (It's in Spanish I hope you don't mind) it exercise 9.5.7//page 103.

Comment: That link doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is the level of the course? What title?

Comment: @quasi it's called 'Fundamentos de matemáticas' by professor Zalamea.

Comment: Ok, I found a copy of the book, and you're right, the author does say $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. But based on the preceding material in the book, and the other exercises, I'm fairly sure it was just a typo. So as not to stress over an impossible exercise, just assume the intended restriction was $a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a^2 \ge b \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming "square" means square of a rational (otherwise any positive real is the square of a real number), it's not true if $a$ and $b$ are not assumed rational.  For example, with $0 < b < 1/4$ and $a = b + 1/4$ we have $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}+\sqrt{a-\sqrt{b}} = 1$.

Comment: Oops, sorry: fixed it.